# Is it teaching field or teaching line?

Tags: word-usage

I happen to read the introduction to a professor of English from the English and Foreign Languages University, Hyderabad. One of the sentences is given below.

> She has been in the teaching line for the past five years.

I heard some people utter 'teaching field'. I would like to know whether it is teaching line or teaching field or is there any other better expression than these two usages?

Comment: Both are good, although *line* is normally used if you are selling something. *Profession* might be better.

Comment: I've heard "in the teaching business" in informal situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a quick look at [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Teaching+field%2C+teaching+line&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CTeaching%20field%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bteaching%20field%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTeaching%20Field%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cteaching%20line%3B%2Cc0) shows that "teaching field" is a much more common turn of phrase, but "teaching line" is also present. A look through the results for "teaching line" shows that although it’s often used as "teaching line by line" or in reference to teaching "line" (i.e. drawing techniques), there are some references to "teaching line" itself.

I would add that "teaching line" may have connotations of [front line](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Front+line). That is, the people on the front line of teaching are the ones *actually* in the classroom, delivering the course content. You can be in the field of teaching but never have to deliver content (i.e. some head teachers aren’t allocated "contact time" with the pupils, some people study teaching and formulate methods but do not deliver content; they are in the field but not on the front line).

Comment: your answer indicates that both expressions are possible.my doubt has not been fully clarified.However , thank you for your response

Comment: "Line" is common in British English (maybe American too?) for "profession, field, specialisation, trade, business, etc", e.g. My father sells meat, bread, fruit and vegetables; he has been in the grocery line for 20 years.

Comment: Thank you Mr Michael

Comment: Aren't 'in teaching' and 'in the teaching profession'  far more idiomatic? Adding 'is in [the]' to [Google searches](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+in+teaching%2Cis+in+the+teaching+profession%2Cis+in+the+teachimg+line%2Cis+n+the+teaching+field&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20in%20teaching%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20in%20the%20teaching%20profession%3B%2Cc0) would eliminate virtually all 'teaching line by line' false positives.